# Community Building missing from network profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts

With the name change, Community Building fell off the "accounts" list on my [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/505925/monica-cellio?tab=accounts):

[image: part of my account list]

I know Pops said there are a lot of places to update for a name change.  Looks like this one got missed.

It looks like this isn't a problem on the site profile, only the network profile.  From Andy's meta user page (since he conveniently has this site in his top five, unlike me):

[image: Andy's account list]

Comment: Related resource: [shouldiblamecaching.com](http://shouldiblamecaching.com) :) Yeah, reproduced for me in Chrome 39 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin caching is why I waited a few hours to report it.  Just how laggy *is* this cache, anyway?

Comment: Wow, another major bug: Flair and Network Profile down, no matter what site you access it from.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin I don't know what you mean by that, but if you think it's part of this, feel free to edit.

Comment: I'm trying to use too many tabs at once, sorry my clipboard is overflowing. See the edit to my comment. But can you still access your network profile or flair? I can't for anyone with a CB account.

Comment: I can access my network profile, yes.  (Just did after seeing your comment, though it might, err, be cached.)  And I just checked flair, which definitely wasn't cached, and I'm seeing it just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

stackexchange.com caches site lists and a few other things pretty heavily. For example, it still thought that CB was called Moderators on /sites.

This would normally resolve itself in a few hours/days, but I kicked it until it updated faster, so you should be all set.

Comment: Working for me now -- thanks!